# complex mysql query with 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

now i have three tables ok?

1. catgories | cat_id
2. areas | area_id
3. ads | cat_id - area_id

now i want get the the areas under the catgories with contain the ads
this mean
- catgorty
-- area contant catgorty ads
example i have cars as a catgory and egypt as area and a car for sale as ads
now i want show the areas under the catgories which contain ads
this mean
i have egypt usa canda
and one ads in egypt
now i want show it like
cars
-- egypt
and if i have one more ad in the usa
it appear
cars
--egypt
--usa
this mean give me the areas with contain ads under that catgory

Comment: You really need to clarify your question, I just can't make any sense out of it right now...

Comment: @moustafa now i want open stackoverflow answer some questions now see the complex mysql query this mean i have chance answer open see this *hit put cmment now tell me Do you know what `Grammar` means? Try spellchecker before posting a question!

Answer (score 1):

countries with adds:

```
SELECT *
  FROM areas
 WHERE area_id in (SELECT area_id FROM ads)
```

countries with adds for cars:

```
SELECT *
  FROM areas
 WHERE area_id in (
    SELECT ads.area_id
      FROM ads,categories
     WHERE ads.cat_id = categories.cat_id
       AND categories.cat_name = 'cars')
```

is that what you meant?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT cat_id, group_concat(area_id) from ads group by cat_id;
```

Assuming *cat_id* is the actual value (**cars**) and not an auto_increment. If so, use `INNER JOIN`.